# UIPopoverController crashes on iPad but works on the iPad simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, exc-bad-access, uipopovercontroller

I have an iPad app that has an UIPopOverController that is called from a seque. When the button is pushed the popover is presented. The user selects one of the items from the popover and the popover is dismissed. However, when the user pushes the button a second time, the app crashes. The weird part is that it works fine in the simulator but running it on a iPad device it crashes. I receive the following error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The following is my code:

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController<KeypadDelegate,PickerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>    
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIPopoverController *myPopOver;
@end

@implementation ViewController
//...
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"popOverSearchCustomerSegue"])
   {

       if([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]])
       {
           [self.myPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
           self.myPopOver = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
       }
       UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
    self.myPopOver = popoverSegue.popoverController; // this is where it errors out on the second time the button is pushed.
    [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
   }
   else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushProposalSegue"])
   {
       ProposalViewController *propViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       propViewController.customerID = cust.ID;
       propViewController.customerTitle = self.title;
   }
}
//This method is called by the popover controller when the user selects a row
-(void) myCallBack:(SearchCustomer *)ff
{
    custID = ff.ID;
    [self.myPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    cust = [custDOA getRecords:custID];
    [self setFields];
    [self setButtons:YES];
}
This is my interface for my popover that has a searchBar controller:
@interface CustomerSearchViewController :         UITableViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *customerSearchList;
@property (weak, nonatomic) ViewController *delegate;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *resultsCustomerSearchList;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@end
```

Comment: You need to provide the stack trace and more information on the crash. Which line is the crash occurring on?

Comment: The error message that i am receiving is:*** -[UIView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17817efc0. This is occurring on the following line: self.myPopOver = popoverSegue.popoverController; // this is where it errors out on the second time the button is pushed.

Comment: Hmm. MyPopover is holding an invalid pointer that wasn't nilled when the previous popover was dismissed so when you assign a new value it attempts to release the old value, but this object has been deallocated already. Change this property from `strong` to `weak`

Comment: Ok narrow it down. I have search bar controller in my popover. If I take off the search bar controller, it doesn't crash. If I add back the search bar controller, it crashes.

Comment: What is the delegate for the search bar?

Comment: In my interface for the customerSearchviewcontroller which is the popover and has the search bar, I have the following property @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar; I used the searchBar Controller. I'm not sure about the delegate for the search bar. This is my first iPad app